# How do I check constant?

Tags: r

`structure(list(Date_Time = structure(c(235L, 235L, 235L, 235L, 
252L, 252L, 252L, 252L, 253L, 253L), .Label = c("1/1/2019 0:10", 
"1/1/2019 0:25", "1/1/2019 0:40", "1/1/2019 0:55", "1/1/2019 1:10", 
"1/1/2019 1:25", "1/1/2019 1:40", "1/1/2019 1:55", "1/1/2019 10:10", 
"1/1/2019 10:25", "1/1/2019 10:40", "1/1/2019 10:55", "1/1/2019 11:10", 
"1/1/2019 11:25", "1/1/2019 11:40", "1/1/2019 11:55", "1/1/2019 12:10", 
"1/1/2019 12:25", "1/1/2019 12:40", "1/1/2019 12:55", "1/1/2019 13:10", 
"1/1/2019 13:25", "1/1/2019 13:40", "1/1/2019 13:55", "1/1/2019 14:10", 
"1/1/2019 14:25", "1/1/2019 14:40", "1/1/2019 14:55", "1/1/2019 15:10", 
"1/1/2019 15:25", "1/1/2019 15:40", "1/1/2019 15:55", "1/1/2019 16:10", 
"1/1/2019 16:25", "1/1/2019 16:40", "1/1/2019 16:55", "1/1/2019 17:10", 
"1/1/2019 17:25", "1/1/2019 17:40", "1/1/2019 17:55", "1/1/2019 18:10", 
"1/1/2019 18:25", "1/1/2019 18:40", "1/1/2019 18:55", "1/1/2019 19:10", 
"1/1/2019 19:25", "1/1/2019 19:40", "1/1/2019 19:55", "1/1/2019 2:10", 
"1/1/2019 2:25", "1/1/2019 2:40", "1/1/2019 2:55", "1/1/2019 20:10", 
"1/1/2019 20:25", "1/1/2019 20:40", "1/1/2019 20:55", "1/1/2019 21:10", 
"1/1/2019 21:25", "1/1/2019 21:40", "1/1/2019 21:55", "1/1/2019 22:10", 
"1/1/2019 22:25", "1/1/2019 22:40", "1/1/2019 22:55", "1/1/2019 23:10", 
"1/1/2019 23:25", "1/1/2019 23:40", "1/1/2019 23:55", "1/1/2019 3:10", 
"1/1/2019 3:25", "1/1/2019 3:40", "1/1/2019 3:55", "1/1/2019 4:10", 
"1/1/2019 4:25", "1/1/2019 4:40", "1/1/2019 4:55", "1/1/2019 5:10", 
"1/1/2019 5:25", "1/1/2019 5:40", "1/1/2019 5:55", "1/1/2019 6:10", 
"1/1/2019 6:25", "1/1/2019 6:40", "1/1/2019 6:55", "1/1/2019 7:10", 
"1/1/2019 7:25", "1/1/2019 7:40", "1/1/2019 7:55", "1/1/2019 8:10", 
"1/1/2019 8:25", "1/1/2019 8:40", "1/1/2019 8:55", "1/1/2019 9:10", 
"1/1/2019 9:25", "1/1/2019 9:40", "1/1/2019 9:55", "1/2/2019 0:10", 
"1/2/2019 0:25", "1/2/2019 0:40", "1/2/2019 0:55", "1/2/2019 1:10", 
"1/2/2019 1:25", "1/2/2019 1:40", "1/2/2019 1:55", "1/2/2019 10:10", 
"1/2/2019 10:25", "1/2/2019 10:40", "1/2/2019 10:55", "1/2/2019 11:10", 
"1/2/2019 11:25", "1/2/2019 11:40", "1/2/2019 11:41", "1/2/2019 11:55", 
"1/2/2019 12:10", "1/2/2019 12:25", "1/2/2019 12:40", "1/2/2019 12:55", 
"1/2/2019 13:10", "1/2/2019 13:25", "1/2/2019 13:40", "1/2/2019 13:55", 
"1/2/2019 14:10", "1/2/2019 14:25", "1/2/2019 14:40", "1/2/2019 14:55", 
"1/2/2019 15:10", "1/2/2019 15:25", "1/2/2019 15:40", "1/2/2019 15:55", 
"1/2/2019 16:10", "1/2/2019 16:25", "1/2/2019 16:40", "1/2/2019 16:55", 
"1/2/2019 17:10", "1/2/2019 17:25", "1/2/2019 17:40", "1/2/2019 17:55", 
"1/2/2019 18:10", "1/2/2019 18:25", "1/2/2019 18:40", "1/2/2019 18:55", 
"1/2/2019 19:10", "1/2/2019 19:25", "1/2/2019 19:40", "1/2/2019 19:55", 
"1/2/2019 2:10", "1/2/2019 2:25", "1/2/2019 2:40", "1/2/2019 2:55", 
"1/2/2019 20:10", "1/2/2019 20:25", "1/2/2019 20:40", "1/2/2019 20:55", 
"1/2/2019 21:10", "1/2/2019 21:25", "1/2/2019 21:40", "1/2/2019 21:55", 
"1/2/2019 22:10", "1/2/2019 22:25", "1/2/2019 22:40", "1/2/2019 22:55", 
"1/2/2019 23:10", "1/2/2019 23:25", "1/2/2019 23:40", "1/2/2019 23:55", 
"1/2/2019 3:10", "1/2/2019 3:25", "1/2/2019 3:40", "1/2/2019 3:55", 
"1/2/2019 4:10", "1/2/2019 4:25", "1/2/2019 4:40", "1/2/2019 4:55", 
"1/2/2019 5:10", "1/2/2019 5:25", "1/2/2019 5:40", "1/2/2019 5:55", 
"1/2/2019 6:10", "1/2/2019 6:25", "1/2/2019 6:40", "1/2/2019 6:55", 
"1/2/2019 7:10", "1/2/2019 7:25", "1/2/2019 7:40", "1/2/2019 7:55", 
"1/2/2019 8:10", "1/2/2019 8:25", "1/2/2019 8:40", "1/2/2019 8:55", 
"1/2/2019 9:10", "1/2/2019 9:25", "1/2/2019 9:26", "1/2/2019 9:40", 
"1/2/2019 9:55", "12/27/2018 10:10", "12/27/2018 10:25", "12/27/2018 10:40", 
"12/27/2018 10:55", "12/27/2018 11:10", "12/27/2018 11:25", "12/27/2018 11:40", 
"12/27/2018 11:55", "12/27/2018 12:10", "12/27/2018 12:25", "12/27/2018 12:40", 
"12/27/2018 12:55", "12/27/2018 13:10", "12/27/2018 13:25", "12/27/2018 13:40", 
"12/27/2018 13:55", "12/27/2018 14:10", "12/27/2018 14:25", "12/27/2018 14:40", 
"12/27/2018 14:55", "12/27/2018 15:10", "12/27/2018 15:25", "12/27/2018 15:40", 
"12/27/2018 15:55", "12/27/2018 16:10", "12/27/2018 16:25", "12/27/2018 16:40", 
"12/27/2018 16:55", "12/27/2018 17:10", "12/27/2018 17:25", "12/27/2018 17:40", 
"12/27/2018 17:55", "12/27/2018 18:10", "12/27/2018 18:25", "12/27/2018 18:40", 
"12/27/2018 18:55", "12/27/2018 19:10", "12/27/2018 19:25", "12/27/2018 19:40", 
"12/27/2018 19:55", "12/27/2018 2:55", "12/27/2018 20:10", "12/27/2018 20:25", 
"12/27/2018 20:40", "12/27/2018 20:55", "12/27/2018 21:10", "12/27/2018 21:25", 
"12/27/2018 21:40", "12/27/2018 21:55", "12/27/2018 22:10", "12/27/2018 22:25", 
"12/27/2018 22:40", "12/27/2018 22:55", "12/27/2018 23:10", "12/27/2018 23:25", 
"12/27/2018 23:40", "12/27/2018 23:55", "12/27/2018 3:10", "12/27/2018 3:25", 
"12/27/2018 3:40", "12/27/2018 3:55", "12/27/2018 4:10", "12/27/2018 4:25", 
"12/27/2018 4:40", "12/27/2018 4:55", "12/27/2018 5:10", "12/27/2018 5:25", 
"12/27/2018 5:40", "12/27/2018 5:55", "12/27/2018 6:10", "12/27/2018 6:25", 
"12/27/2018 6:40", "12/27/2018 6:55", "12/27/2018 7:10", "12/27/2018 7:25", 
"12/27/2018 7:40", "12/27/2018 7:55", "12/27/2018 8:10", "12/27/2018 8:25", 
"12/27/2018 8:40", "12/27/2018 8:55", "12/27/2018 9:10", "12/27/2018 9:25", 
"12/27/2018 9:40", "12/27/2018 9:55", "12/28/2018 0:10", "12/28/2018 0:25", 
"12/28/2018 0:40", "12/28/2018 0:55", "12/28/2018 1:10", "12/28/2018 1:25", 
"12/28/2018 1:40", "12/28/2018 1:55", "12/28/2018 10:10", "12/28/2018 10:25", 
"12/28/2018 10:40", "12/28/2018 10:55", "12/28/2018 11:10", "12/28/2018 11:25", 
"12/28/2018 11:40", "12/28/2018 11:55", "12/28/2018 12:10", "12/28/2018 12:25", 
"12/28/2018 12:40", "12/28/2018 12:55", "12/28/2018 13:10", "12/28/2018 13:25", 
"12/28/2018 13:40", "12/28/2018 13:55", "12/28/2018 14:10", "12/28/2018 14:25", 
"12/28/2018 14:40", "12/28/2018 14:55", "12/28/2018 15:10", "12/28/2018 15:25", 
"12/28/2018 15:40", "12/28/2018 15:55", "12/28/2018 16:10", "12/28/2018 16:25", 
"12/28/2018 16:40", "12/28/2018 16:55", "12/28/2018 17:10", "12/28/2018 17:25", 
"12/28/2018 17:40", "12/28/2018 17:55", "12/28/2018 18:10", "12/28/2018 18:25", 
"12/28/2018 18:40", "12/28/2018 18:55", "12/28/2018 19:10", "12/28/2018 19:25", 
"12/28/2018 19:40", "12/28/2018 19:55", "12/28/2018 2:10", "12/28/2018 2:25", 
"12/28/2018 2:40", "12/28/2018 2:55", "12/28/2018 20:10", "12/28/2018 20:25", 
"12/28/2018 20:40", "12/28/2018 20:55", "12/28/2018 21:10", "12/28/2018 21:25", 
"12/28/2018 21:40", "12/28/2018 21:55", "12/28/2018 22:10", "12/28/2018 22:25", 
"12/28/2018 22:40", "12/28/2018 22:55", "12/28/2018 23:10", "12/28/2018 23:25", 
"12/28/2018 23:40", "12/28/2018 23:55", "12/28/2018 3:10", "12/28/2018 3:25", 
"12/28/2018 3:40", "12/28/2018 3:55", "12/28/2018 4:10", "12/28/2018 4:11", 
"12/28/2018 4:25", "12/28/2018 4:40", "12/28/2018 4:55", "12/28/2018 5:10", 
"12/28/2018 5:25", "12/28/2018 5:40", "12/28/2018 5:55", "12/28/2018 6:10", 
"12/28/2018 6:25", "12/28/2018 6:40", "12/28/2018 6:55", "12/28/2018 7:10", 
"12/28/2018 7:25", "12/28/2018 7:40", "12/28/2018 7:55", "12/28/2018 8:10", 
"12/28/2018 8:25", "12/28/2018 8:40", "12/28/2018 8:55", "12/28/2018 9:10", 
"12/28/2018 9:25", "12/28/2018 9:40", "12/28/2018 9:55", "12/29/2018 0:10", 
"12/29/2018 0:25", "12/29/2018 0:40", "12/29/2018 0:55", "12/29/2018 1:10", 
"12/29/2018 1:25", "12/29/2018 1:40", "12/29/2018 1:55", "12/29/2018 10:10", 
"12/29/2018 10:25", "12/29/2018 10:40", "12/29/2018 10:55", "12/29/2018 11:10", 
"12/29/2018 11:25", "12/29/2018 11:40", "12/29/2018 11:55", "12/29/2018 12:10", 
"12/29/2018 12:25", "12/29/2018 12:40", "12/29/2018 12:55", "12/29/2018 13:10", 
"12/29/2018 13:25", "12/29/2018 13:40", "12/29/2018 13:55", "12/29/2018 14:10", 
"12/29/2018 14:25", "12/29/2018 14:40", "12/29/2018 14:55", "12/29/2018 15:10", 
"12/29/2018 15:25", "12/29/2018 15:40", "12/29/2018 15:55", "12/29/2018 16:10", 
"12/29/2018 16:25", "12/29/2018 16:40", "12/29/2018 16:55", "12/29/2018 17:10", 
"12/29/2018 17:25", "12/29/2018 17:40", "12/29/2018 17:55", "12/29/2018 18:10", 
"12/29/2018 18:25", "12/29/2018 18:40", "12/29/2018 18:55", "12/29/2018 19:10", 
"12/29/2018 19:25", "12/29/2018 19:40", "12/29/2018 19:55", "12/29/2018 2:10", 
"12/29/2018 2:25", "12/29/2018 2:40", "12/29/2018 2:55", "12/29/2018 20:10", 
"12/29/2018 20:25", "12/29/2018 20:40", "12/29/2018 20:55", "12/29/2018 21:10", 
"12/29/2018 21:25", "12/29/2018 21:40", "12/29/2018 21:55", "12/29/2018 22:10", 
"12/29/2018 22:25", "12/29/2018 22:40", "12/29/2018 22:55", "12/29/2018 23:10", 
"12/29/2018 23:25", "12/29/2018 23:40", "12/29/2018 23:55", "12/29/2018 3:10", 
"12/29/2018 3:25", "12/29/2018 3:40", "12/29/2018 3:55", "12/29/2018 4:10", 
"12/29/2018 4:25", "12/29/2018 4:40", "12/29/2018 4:55", "12/29/2018 5:10", 
"12/29/2018 5:25", "12/29/2018 5:40", "12/29/2018 5:55", "12/29/2018 6:10", 
"12/29/2018 6:25", "12/29/2018 6:40", "12/29/2018 6:55", "12/29/2018 7:10", 
"12/29/2018 7:25", "12/29/2018 7:40", "12/29/2018 7:55", "12/29/2018 8:10", 
"12/29/2018 8:25", "12/29/2018 8:40", "12/29/2018 8:55", "12/29/2018 9:10", 
"12/29/2018 9:25", "12/29/2018 9:40", "12/29/2018 9:55", "12/30/2018 0:10", 
"12/30/2018 0:25", "12/30/2018 0:40", "12/30/2018 0:55", "12/30/2018 1:10", 
"12/30/2018 1:25", "12/30/2018 1:40", "12/30/2018 1:55", "12/30/2018 10:10", 
"12/30/2018 10:25", "12/30/2018 10:40", "12/30/2018 10:55", "12/30/2018 11:10", 
"12/30/2018 11:25", "12/30/2018 11:40", "12/30/2018 11:55", "12/30/2018 12:10", 
"12/30/2018 12:25", "12/30/2018 12:40", "12/30/2018 12:55", "12/30/2018 13:10", 
"12/30/2018 13:25", "12/30/2018 13:40", "12/30/2018 13:55", "12/30/2018 14:10", 
"12/30/2018 14:25", "12/30/2018 14:40", "12/30/2018 14:55", "12/30/2018 15:10", 
"12/30/2018 15:25", "12/30/2018 15:40", "12/30/2018 15:55", "12/30/2018 16:10", 
"12/30/2018 16:25", "12/30/2018 16:40", "12/30/2018 16:55", "12/30/2018 17:10", 
"12/30/2018 17:25", "12/30/2018 17:40", "12/30/2018 17:55", "12/30/2018 18:10", 
"12/30/2018 18:25", "12/30/2018 18:40", "12/30/2018 18:55", "12/30/2018 19:10", 
"12/30/2018 19:25", "12/30/2018 19:40", "12/30/2018 19:55", "12/30/2018 2:10", 
"12/30/2018 2:25", "12/30/2018 2:40", "12/30/2018 2:55", "12/30/2018 20:10", 
"12/30/2018 20:25", "12/30/2018 20:40", "12/30/2018 20:55", "12/30/2018 21:10", 
"12/30/2018 21:25", "12/30/2018 21:40", "12/30/2018 21:55", "12/30/2018 22:10", 
"12/30/2018 22:25", "12/30/2018 22:40", "12/30/2018 22:55", "12/30/2018 23:10", 
"12/30/2018 23:25", "12/30/2018 23:40", "12/30/2018 23:55", "12/30/2018 3:10", 
"12/30/2018 3:25", "12/30/2018 3:40", "12/30/2018 3:55", "12/30/2018 4:10", 
"12/30/2018 4:25", "12/30/2018 4:40", "12/30/2018 4:55", "12/30/2018 5:10", 
"12/30/2018 5:25", "12/30/2018 5:40", "12/30/2018 5:55", "12/30/2018 6:10", 
"12/30/2018 6:25", "12/30/2018 6:40", "12/30/2018 6:55", "12/30/2018 7:10", 
"12/30/2018 7:25", "12/30/2018 7:40", "12/30/2018 7:55", "12/30/2018 8:10", 
"12/30/2018 8:25", "12/30/2018 8:40", "12/30/2018 8:55", "12/30/2018 9:10", 
"12/30/2018 9:25", "12/30/2018 9:40", "12/30/2018 9:55", "12/31/2018 0:10", 
"12/31/2018 0:25", "12/31/2018 0:40", "12/31/2018 0:55", "12/31/2018 1:10", 
"12/31/2018 1:25", "12/31/2018 1:40", "12/31/2018 1:55", "12/31/2018 10:10", 
"12/31/2018 10:25", "12/31/2018 10:40", "12/31/2018 10:55", "12/31/2018 11:10", 
"12/31/2018 11:25", "12/31/2018 11:40", "12/31/2018 11:55", "12/31/2018 12:10", 
"12/31/2018 12:25", "12/31/2018 12:40", "12/31/2018 12:55", "12/31/2018 13:10", 
"12/31/2018 13:25", "12/31/2018 13:40", "12/31/2018 13:55", "12/31/2018 14:10", 
"12/31/2018 14:25", "12/31/2018 14:40", "12/31/2018 14:55", "12/31/2018 15:10", 
"12/31/2018 15:25", "12/31/2018 15:40", "12/31/2018 15:55", "12/31/2018 16:10", 
"12/31/2018 16:25", "12/31/2018 16:40", "12/31/2018 16:55", "12/31/2018 17:10", 
"12/31/2018 17:25", "12/31/2018 17:40", "12/31/2018 17:55", "12/31/2018 18:10", 
"12/31/2018 18:25", "12/31/2018 18:40", "12/31/2018 18:55", "12/31/2018 19:10", 
"12/31/2018 19:25", "12/31/2018 19:40", "12/31/2018 19:55", "12/31/2018 2:10", 
"12/31/2018 2:25", "12/31/2018 2:40", "12/31/2018 2:55", "12/31/2018 20:10", 
"12/31/2018 20:25", "12/31/2018 20:40", "12/31/2018 20:55", "12/31/2018 21:10", 
"12/31/2018 21:25", "12/31/2018 21:40", "12/31/2018 21:55", "12/31/2018 22:10", 
"12/31/2018 22:25", "12/31/2018 22:40", "12/31/2018 22:55", "12/31/2018 23:10", 
"12/31/2018 23:25", "12/31/2018 23:40", "12/31/2018 23:55", "12/31/2018 3:10", 
"12/31/2018 3:25", "12/31/2018 3:40", "12/31/2018 3:55", "12/31/2018 4:10", 
"12/31/2018 4:25", "12/31/2018 4:40", "12/31/2018 4:55", "12/31/2018 5:10", 
"12/31/2018 5:25", "12/31/2018 5:40", "12/31/2018 5:55", "12/31/2018 6:10", 
"12/31/2018 6:25", "12/31/2018 6:40", "12/31/2018 6:55", "12/31/2018 7:10", 
"12/31/2018 7:25", "12/31/2018 7:40", "12/31/2018 7:55", "12/31/2018 8:10", 
"12/31/2018 8:25", "12/31/2018 8:40", "12/31/2018 8:55", "12/31/2018 9:10", 
"12/31/2018 9:25", "12/31/2018 9:40", "12/31/2018 9:55"), class = "Datetime"), 
 Asset = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("AHU_01", "AHU_100", "AHU_101", "AHU_32"), class = "factor"),  Sub_asset = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Supply = c(0,68.1499, 62.1832, 0, 0, 68.1085, 62.1173, 0, 0, 68.212),  Return_water = c(64.3895, 69.3196, 53.1641, 59.2634, 64.1041,69.2989, 53.1172, 59.2415, 64.0602, 69.4024),  supply_constant_check = structure(c(2L,2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Constant","Not Constant"), class = "factor"), 
 return_water_constant_check = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Not Constant", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA,10L), class = "data.frame")`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d70iI.png)I have a dataframe as below which contains date_time column and certain asset and Sub_asset tags. I need to find identify the constant values under the column Supply and Return_water column. if values under these columns are constant for 6 rows then I want to mention it as constant by inserting a new column next to it. Also I want to check for the constants under Supply and Return_water column with grouping asset and Sub_asset column variables. Please suggest me a R code for this.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to work with?

Comment: You can share the data with `dput(head(data, 10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sequence` with `rle` to count how many repeat values there are. With `dplyr`:

```
constant <- function(x, n = 6) {
  sequence(rle(as.character(x))$lengths) >= n
}

df[is.na(df$Sub_asset),]$Sub_asset <- "NA"
df %>%
  split(list(.$Asset, .$Sub_asset)) %>%
  lapply(function(x) {
    arrange(x, Date_Time) %>%
    mutate(supply_constant_check = ifelse(constant(Supply), "Constant", "Not Constant"),
           return_water_constant_check = ifelse(constant(Return_water), "Constant", "Not Constant"))
  }) %>%
  bind_rows()

# A tibble: 10 x 7
   Date_Time Asset   Sub_asset Supply Return_water supply_constant_check return_water_constant_che~
       <int> <fct>   <chr>      <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>                     
 1       235 AHU_01  NA           0           64.4 Not Constant          Not Constant              
 2       252 AHU_01  NA           0           64.1 Not Constant          Not Constant              
 3       253 AHU_01  NA           0           64.1 Not Constant          Not Constant              
 4       235 AHU_100 NA          68.1         69.3 Not Constant          Not Constant              
 5       252 AHU_100 NA          68.1         69.3 Not Constant          Not Constant              
 6       253 AHU_100 NA          68.2         69.4 Not Constant          Not Constant              
 7       235 AHU_101 NA          62.2         53.2 Not Constant          Not Constant              
 8       252 AHU_101 NA          62.1         53.1 Not Constant          Not Constant              
 9       235 AHU_32  NA           0           59.3 Not Constant          Not Constant              
10       252 AHU_32  NA           0           59.2 Not Constant          Not Constant
```

Comment: Hey Paul, Code is working but group by is not happening if i have more category under Asset column.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with multiple assets/subassets. One alternative could be to `split` `df` and do a `lapply`.

Comment: I have added the data with multiple assets for your reference.

Comment: Please add it to your original post, don't add an image, instead use `dput()` in R and copy the output into the post.

Comment: Hey Paul, I have added the sample data above.

Comment: I used `group_by()` inappropriately in my previous answer. This update uses `split()` and `lapply()` instead. It should work for you now.

Comment: Sure. Thank you so much...

Comment: No problems, please [up-vote and accept](//https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if you think it is the best solution for your problem.